# Run Capybara without opening browser

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I wrote simple console script for scraping with capybara (selenium driver) but doesn't want browser to appear. I just wan't text to be written on console.

Is possible to run capybara wihout opening browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [headless-webkit driver](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) for Capybara that would avoid opening a browser window.

If you are not tied to the Capybara API and don't need to worry about JavaScript then [mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) would probably be a simpler way to interact with Web sites.

Comment: I need to worry about JavaScript :)